# how to invoke IE to open a local html file?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 2.0. And I want to invoke IE to open an html file located under pages sub-folder of my current executable.

Since my program may run under Windows Vista, I want to invoke IE under administrative permissions (Run As Administrator).

Any code to make reference? I am especially interested in how to write portable code, which works on both Windows Vista and Windows XP (I think Windows XP does not have function like Run As Administrator)

EDIT 1:

I am using the following code, but there is no UAC (User Access Control) prompt message box opened up to let me select Continue to run with Administrator. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
    startInfo.Verb = "RunAs";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\test\default.html";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

thanks in advance,
Geroge

Comment: Does it really have to be IE or do you just want to launch an HTML file with whatever the default browser is?

Comment: While I'm giving you the third degree, I might as well ask why you would want to launch IE to run as admin..

Comment: Hi Steven, I need to use IE since I am using Silverlight in html. I think firefox does not support Silverlight?

Comment: Hi Steven, I am launching IE to open a Silverlight player to play local files, I find if I do not start with Administrator, the files can not be loaded successfully.

Comment: FF supports Silverlight, but there have (unsurprisingly) been a few issues.

Comment: Really? Microsoft releases Silverlight Firefox plug-in?

Comment: Can you share me the link? I am very confused.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

Comment: Why would you want to run with administrative permissions? If IE isn't on the machine (e.g. Win7 "E Sku") then your code will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process the_process = new Process();
the_process.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
the_process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
the_process.StartInfo.Arguments = "myfile.html";
the_process.Start();
```

the verb "runas" will make it prompt the UAC And run under administrative priviliges.

you can run that code underboth vista and XP. It will yield same effect. 
As for the file which you want to open, 
you can pass it as the argument to iexplore.exe by using
the_process.arguments = "

Comment: Class Process has no constructor which accepts one string type parameter.

Comment: Hi Anirudh, please refer to edit 1 section of my original post. The current issue is there is no UAC (User Access Control) prompt message box opened up to let me select Continue to run with Administrator. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: sorry my bad that i put in an argument for the constructor. are you running the visual studio in adminstrator? I just tried it on machine and it ran properly. And then it occured to me, when has ever UAC prompt appeared to run iexplore?

Comment: run it with some other applciation which needs administrator rights, it will work!

Comment: your welcome george. Do let me know if any further trouble comes up.

Answer (score 3):

For working with relative paths, give a look to the [GetFullPath method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx).

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(@".\dir\dir2"), "file.html");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", fullPath);
```

Comment: Hi CMS, where in your code you start with "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Hi CMS, please refer to edit 1 section of my original post. The current issue is there is no UAC (User Access Control) prompt message box opened up to let me select Continue to run with Administrator. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"C:\mypage.html");
```

Comment: Hi John, please refer to edit 1 section of my original post. The current issue is there is no UAC (User Access Control) prompt message box opened up to let me select Continue to run with Administrator. Any ideas what is wrong?